# Symbolic breakpoint to catch OS alerts

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints, lldb, symbolic-breakpoint

Consider location services are disabled by the user and when location is requested by the app, iOS shows alert

"Turn on Location Services to Allow "" to Determine Your Location"

Is there any way we can set a symbolic breakpoint to know which line of code actually triggers this iOS alert.

I have tried

-[UIAlertView show]

but dint work

Comment: Sounds like you have a CLLocationManager invoking some calls. The OS will only popup if you use CL API. Gotta find where you are calling those methods

Comment: I found out where, but my thought here is can it be done through symbolic breakpoints..

Comment: Once you allowed location service from startUpdateLocation then only user has authority to stop location service from setting. As you are saying that user stop location service when app is in background mode. Then there is no way to detect. But when user again run the app iin fpreground mode then it will again ask to enable service

Answer (score 1):

All iOS system alerts are shown by a different process in a different window on top of your app. So it is not possible to set a breakpoint for all system alerts.

You can however set a symbolic breakpoint to find the code that causes this alert to be shown; `-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`, `-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` and `-[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]`.